# Changing ti.barcode view size

Tags: appcelerator, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm fiddling around with ti.barcode scanner module, but it seems it's always fullscreen.

Is there a way to make it use a part of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS you can use SquareCamera: https://github.com/mikefogg/SquareCamera which allows you to have the camera inside a view and scan qr codes too.

But if you want to have it cross platform I would go with the overlay variant

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can embed the ti.barcode to a smaller view, since you don't add it to a controller.

Have you tried to set the size of the module in the capture method?

The possible workaround is to create a view with your stuff and place it in the overlay property of the capture method